# jquery search for text, then get parent. then insert new data

Tags: jquery

The goal of this is not to redesign my html or to use a different css selection method. Then goal of this is to:

Using jQuery to:

- Find the `<span>` that contains "Walnuts"
- Get the parent element `<p>`
- Insert a new `<p><span>...` after that element.

I'm not looking for a different way to insert "Cashews" after walnuts. I'm solely looking for the procedure that is mentioned above.

Here's a fiddle -->http://jsfiddle.net/V3ucA

HTML:

```
<div class='master'>
  <div class='big1'>
    <p class='medium1'>
        <span>Peanuts</span>
    </p>
    <p class='medium1'>
        <span>Walnuts</span>
    </p>
    <p class='medium1'>
        <span>Pecans</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='master'>
  <div class='big1'>
    <p class='medium1'>
        <span>Bananas</span>
    </p>
    <p class='medium1'>
        <span>Apples</span>
    </p>
    <p class='medium1'>
        <span>Oranges</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id='clickme'>Click me</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    $(".big1 > p > span:contains('Walnuts')")
        .parent()
        .insertAfter("<p class='medium1'><span>Cashews</span></p>");
   });
});
```

AGAIN...THIS IS NOT WHAT IM LOOKING FOR:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/), not [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickme').click(function () {
        $(".big1 > p > span:contains('Walnuts')")
            .parent()
            .after("<p class='medium1'><span>Cashews</span></p>");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v2wNk/)

- after() - if the right hand side has to be inserted after the left hand side element
- insertAfter() - if the LHS has to be inserted after RHS and if you want a reference to the inserted element to be returned

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was close!

Answer (score 1):

use `.after()` and `.append()` for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $(".big1 > p > span:contains('Walnuts')")
       .parent()
        .after("<p class='medium1'><span>Cashews</span></p>");
});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3ucA/6/)

Comment: the generated html is not the same.... it generates a `p` inside another one - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V3ucA/5/

Comment: Thanks! but Arun beat you to it!

Comment: @bagofmilk haha, its ok brother.. he's a master in jquery. I'm just a beginner in this.